Getting customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed and cannot be upgraded from this location
I have seen the solution that suggests removing this registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions{GUID}
All that does for me is allow the plug-in to be installed one time, but the next time an updated version is published, the same error gets thrown when excel tries to install the new version.  Is there a root cause that can be addressed?
I have tried deleting this key : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions{GUID}
Doing this is not a long-term solution because the same error is thrown then the plug-in is updated.
I need a solution that either does not require me to add registry entries to all of the consumer's computers which will run this add-in, or offers a way to automatically add then during the install process.
